# Generar pdf en angular

Tags: angular

Ayuda amigos me genera este error:

[image]

Estoy haciendo un generador de php y lo tengo de esta manera pero no me funciona

ts del componente

```js
convertJsonToPdf(){

  var elem = document.getElementById("generate");
      var doc = new jsPDF ('1', 'pt', 'letter');
      var elem = document.getElementById("table");
      var data = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);

      var positions = [];
      doc.autoTable(data.columns, data.rows);

      doc.save("table.pdf");

    }
```

html del componente

```html
<button 
  type="button"
  class="botonclic2 btn btn-outline-info"
  (click)="convertJsonToPdf()">
  Generar PDF
</button>
```

Me guie de esto:

> Hello, try it.
>
> To work with jspdf-autotable in angular 5, one must install jspdf and jspdf-autotable via npm
>
> ```
> npm install jspdf-autotable --save
> ```
>
> also add the jspdf and jspdf-autotable files to the scripts array in angular-cli.json
>
> ```
> "scripts": [
> "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
> "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
> ],
> ```
>
> and in component never import jspdf or jspdf-autotable just
>
> ```
> declare var jsPDF: any;
> ```
>
> Of course before working with **jspdf-autotable** one should install `jspdf` and for development `@types/jspdf` via `npm`
>
> ```
> npm install jspdf --save
> npm install @types/jspdf --save-dev
> ```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de angular usas?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var doc = new jsPDF ('1', 'pt', 'letter');
```

aquí debes colocar `l` en vez de `1`

Comment: Hola Marien, gracias por colaborar en el sitio. Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido reporta como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. ¿Podrías añadir una breve descripción de por qué poenr una `l` en lugar de un `1` solucionaría el problema?

Comment: El primer parametro al inicializar el jspdf corresponde a l = landscape o p=portrait. y la persona tenia colocado 1 y no es lo correcto

Answer (score 0):

Pero para php solo agrega las referencias html2Canvas y jspdf ejemplo:

```js
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.body , function() {
  pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<body>
 <div >
 
  <p id="pdfContenido">Hola pdf...</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, seguramente ya resolviste la cuestion. pero veo que estas seleccionando un elemento del DOM de esta manera. var elem = document.getElementById("generate");
En angular eso es incorrecto. para eso puedes usar @ViewChild('nombreReferencia'): nombreReferencia: ElementRef;

y en el objeto del dom asi: <input #nombreReferencia />

Esa manera de usar el selector es insegura en angular. y de seguro tu aplicacion no correra en un webworker porque ahi no existe la variable global 'document'. Saludos!